# How to shrinkwrap a plane to form the shape of another object

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have a plane made up of hexagonal holes. I want to deform it in such a way it matches the tip of the microphone (marked in orange). I tried the shrinkwrap modifier but it deformed all the holes down the beveled sides of the object until they were crushed together. The mesh looked okay along the flat however.

I've tried other modifiers and I can't seem to find any tutorials that might help.

Will I have to use particles for the hexagonal holes and distribute them across the object that way?
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot explaining how it should look like ?

Comment: it seems complicated, maybe use a normal map to fake it?

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping for a quick way of modelling a plane into a bevelled shape, but I just complicated the issue.

I used the proportional editing tool instead to turn the plane spherical and then to flatten the top. Worked like a charm!

Comment: i am pretty sure you could also just use the simple deform modifier, which has the advantage that it is non-destructive.